# Extract substring from string giving None

Tags: python, regex

I have a main string and I want to get a substring from it using regex. but its giving [] as result of  `findall`

**My mainString is**

```
mainString="[31m\n[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError import KeyPair: InvalidKeyPair.Duplicate: The keypair 'avtx-ctrl-key' already exists.\n\tstatus code: 400, request id: a56bb69b-0dc1-4c2f-a0c0-96d1be7c1efe[0m\n\n[0m[0m[0m\n[31m\n[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError"

import re
start = re.escape("Error ")
end   = re.escape('[0m\n\n')
result = re.findall('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), mainString)
```

**and my desired output is**

```
Error import KeyPair: InvalidKeyPair.Duplicate: The keypair 'avtx-ctrl-key' already exists.status code: 400, request id: a56bb69b-0dc1-4c2f-a0c0-96d1be7c1efe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?s)Error:\s*(?:\[\d+m)+(.*?)(?=(?:\[\d+m)*\n\n)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qeRTZq/1/). Details:

- `Error:` - a literal string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:\[\d+m)+`  - one or more repetitions of `[`, 1+ digits and `m`
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(?=(?:\[\d+m)*\n\n)` - up to the first occurrence of 0+ sequences of `[`, 1+ digits + `m` and then a double newline char.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/JNUPku):

```py
import re
mainString = "[31m\n[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError import KeyPair: InvalidKeyPair.Duplicate: The keypair 'avtx-ctrl-key' already exists.\n\tstatus code: 400, request id: a56bb69b-0dc1-4c2f-a0c0-96d1be7c1efe[0m\n\n[0m[0m[0m\n[31m\n[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError"
start = r"Error:\s*(?:\[\d+m)+"
end   = r"(?=(?:\[\d+m)*\n\n)"
result = re.findall('%s(.*?)%s' % (start, end), mainString, re.S)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
["Error import KeyPair: InvalidKeyPair.Duplicate: The keypair 'avtx-ctrl-key' already exists.\n\tstatus code: 400, request id: a56bb69b-0dc1-4c2f-a0c0-96d1be7c1efe"]
```

Comment: thanks for answer sir , but there is little bit constraint . I must have to use start and end pattern. because this string will repeat in same mainString and I will use  `findall`  . Can you please suggest something which can work with start and end literal

Comment: @ShahrozPervaz So, start delimiter = `r'Error:\s*(?:\[\d+m)+'`, end delimiter = `(?=(?:\[\d+m)*\n\n)`. The pattern will work with `re.findall`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Done. And If you could kindly refer any good documentation on this document for future use ? It would be really helpful

Comment: @ShahrozPervaz Do you ask for regex docs/reference?

Comment: @ShahrozPervaz I do not know your level of regex knowledge :) so that I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at.